Is there a way of automating Cypress to run specific time instead running manually
I want to run my cypress tests every weekend Automatically and also I want to get some email notifications if the test fail. What are the steps I should take to implement this.

Depends where you want to run it. E.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule.

You could set up a cron job

Are there any specific Config I have to make in cypress

Read this blog by Gleb Bahmutov Trying GitHub Actions - includes the cron section mentioned above.

The question is very broad, I will answer the part specific to Cypress.
Cypress provides a feature called the Module API for building your own way of running the tests, as opposed to cypress open and cypress run which you will be familiar with.

runs Cypress silently in a Nodejs process
provides results in json format (suitable for emailing)

The example at the end of the docs shows a simple node wrapper.js.
// wrapper.js
const cypress = require('cypress')

const runOptions = await cypress.cli.parseRunArguments(process.argv.slice(2))
const results = await cypress.run(runOptions)
// process the "cypress.run()" results

You would need to find Nodejs libraries for the scheduling and emailing to fit into the wrapper, to complete all the features you want.

This sound Goods. Thank you!
